# Retrieving all phones from contacts and tasks

Tags: soql, mobile, android, sdk

I need to retrieve, through two disctinct SOQL queries, the home, mobile and default phones from contacts and tasks but while

MobilePhone and Phone fields work for Contacts HomePhone does not

For Tasks Who.Phone works but Who.MobilePhone does not

what fields should I use in the SOQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task is a special object in Salesforce and you can not directly query on all fields of parent object.

For example you can not query on all the fields of task Owner. Only some global field can be queried. Owner.Email can be used in query but Owner.AnyCustomField__c can not be used in Query. Similarly only few fields can be queried from parent object Who.

But if you query on Contact object field HomePhone can be queried. If you are not able to query this field please check field level security.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a note, SOSL works well for querying on phone numbers since you can specify to search all phone fields as in:

```
FIND {3333333333} IN Phone Fields Returning Contact(Id)
```